# How to set Title in Alert notification using Bluemix push notification service?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm trying to set a title using Bluemix push notification when the unlocked style is in Alert mode, and seems like there is an option in apple documentation to set the Title according to Payload Keys
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1, but I cannot see that option in Bluemix push rest API doc https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/#!/messages/post_apps_applicationId_messages

And I cannot use silent push notification because it's not working when the app is killed by the user and it's not running --references [BlueMix Push Notification - support for Apple localized alert messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407583/bluemix-push-notification-support-for-apple-localized-alert-messages)  And more reference https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/31403

So I just can see that the title's tied to my application name, is there any way to change it not using silent push notification? [image]

I appreciate your answers

Answer (score 0):

As you saw in the Apple Documentation, you can set the title of an alert by setting the parameter title in the `UIAlertController`.

e.g.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
  let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "iOScreator", message:
    "Hello, world!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
  alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

  self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image: alert]

[See this article for more information on that.](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/display-an-alert-view-in-ios8-with-swift)

---

Now it looks like your other question is asking if you can set a title parameter from your actual push notification for the alert.

This isn't supported out of the box, but you could send it as an **Additional Payload** parameter and parse this parameter when you receive the push notification from your device.

[image: payload]

So you would:

1. Send the notification with the title in the **Additional Payload**
2. Receive the notification from the device and get the title from it
3. Set the title in the `UIAlertController`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but I'm basically asking how can I set the title when it's a push notification is in Alert style if de device is unlocked no in a view controller inside the app, I have tried to set different configuration but event if I set it in the  Additional Payload I had to use Silent push notification to get the title and launch a local push notification but unfortunately that does not work if the app is killed by the user which is explained in this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407583/bluemix-push-notification-support-for-apple-localized-alert-messages

Comment: I see. Let me get in touch with the developers to see what options you have.

Comment: So at this time your only option is going to be to send a silent notification and generate your own local notification. I shared your concerns with the service development team, and you can up a feature request here: https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas/filters/top

Comment: Thanks for the info :)